# How to extract last parts of the word based on value

Tags: javascript

I'm looking for a way to extract number of words from string.

For example I have the string below.

```
var word = "Customer Courseware Development and OTB Creation - Learning Center Set Up"

var value = 4;
```

Based on the value above I want to get the last 4 words on the string which is the "Learning Center Set Up"

So far what I've done is below which I only getting the "Up" word.

```
var wordlength = 4;

var str = "Customer Courseware Development and OTB Creation - Learning Center Set Up"

var parts = str.substring(str.lastIndexOf(" ") - length);

console.log(parts);
```

Comment: If you got your answer, you can select anyone as **answered**.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can achieve like this. Split the sentence with `' '` and then slice starting from the `parts.length - wordlength`.

```js
var wordlength = 4;
var str = "Customer Courseware Development and OTB Creation - Learning Center Set Up"
var parts = str.split(' ');

var newStr = parts.slice(parts.length-wordlength, parts.length).join(' ');

console.log(newStr);
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use `Array#slice()` with `join()`

```js
var wordlength = 4;
var str = "Customer Courseware Development and OTB Creation - Learning Center Set Up";
var parts = str.split(' ');
var newString = parts.slice(parts.length-wordlength, parts.length).join(" ");

console.log(newString);
```

Comment: @Bhansa **1st** I won't edit my answer. It is a good answer that solve OP's problem. **2nd** Your answer is not the same as mine. **3rd** The goal is no to answer first and get the upvotes. The goal is to help OP to find a solution by providing a correct and clear solution. OP can now see different answer to help him understand the problem

Comment: Sorry if I said something wrong, but my motive is not to get the upvotes either. I was just pointing that if you can add more info to your answer. So that OP can have more ways. No offense.

Answer (score -1):

*Use*:

```
var word = "Customer Courseware Development and OTB Creation - Learning Center Set Up"
var wordlength = 4

var words = word.split(" ") 
var result = words.slice(words.length - wordlength)
```

Output:

```
Array [ "Learning", "Center", "Set", "Up" ]
```

And then create a string from the above array you got:

```
result.join(" ")
```

Result:

```
"Learning Center Set Up"
```

Comment: why the downvote?? I shared the answer before anyone did.

Comment: A negative argument is a more general answer to the question: `.slice(-wordLength)`. When you say `length - value`, I know you mean `word.length - how_many_words_to_return`, but you don't mention either `length` or `value` anywhere else, and depending on the length of the starting sentence that might produce a small negative argument, for example.

Comment: @PeterBehr Thanks for your input, I'll update my answer.